# Android Studio preview rendering issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view, preview

i have a problem with my Android Studio version 1.2.1.1. As mentioned in title my Preview for API 21/22 doesnt keep correct view sizes, however on phone the view looks just like it should look. Is there a way to solve this?

Link: https://screencloud.net/v/nrjv

I have extended class TextView, so it supports custom fonts:

```
public class FontTextView extends TextView{
public FontTextView(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    readAttributes(context, attrs);
}

public FontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    readAttributes(context, attrs);
}

private void readAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FontTextView);
    int fontIndex = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.FontTextView_customFont, 0);

    this.setTypeface(TypefaceCreator.getTypeface(fontIndex));
    attributes.recycle();
}
}
```

And i have class which builds these fonts while app starts:

```
public class TypefaceCreator {

public static final int HELVETICA_MEDIUM = 0;
public static final int HELVETICA_LIGHT = 1;
public static final int HELVETICA_ITALIC = 2;
public static final int HELVETICA_ROMAN = 3;

private static Typeface light;
private static Typeface italic;
private static Typeface roman;
private static Typeface medium;

private static TypefaceCreator creator;

private TypefaceCreator(Context context){
    light = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf");
    italic = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"HelveticaNeueLTPro-It.otf");
    roman = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf");
    medium = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"HelveticaNeueLTPro-Md.otf");
}

public static TypefaceCreator getInstance(Context context){
    if(creator == null)
        creator = new TypefaceCreator(context);
    return creator;
}

public static Typeface getTypeface(int index){
    switch(index) {
        case HELVETICA_LIGHT:
            return light;
        case HELVETICA_ITALIC:
            return italic;
        case HELVETICA_ROMAN:
            return  roman;
        default:
            return medium;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Set Preview to 17/18 will work fine

Comment: Well, thats not solution to my problem. I am currently working like this, but there should be a way to fix it for higher APIs

Comment: I think the problem is screen resolution also , well there is a difference always in android emulator and real device

Comment: I think screen resolution has no affect on this one, because it is working correctly on lower APIs.